# Display three level hierarchial data display in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, hierarchical-data, presentation

The coding is in ASP.NET 3.5.
Here is the scenario.
I am modifying a page that populates some data.
In that page there is a table that displays pages.
The pages have sub-pages and these sub-pages again have sub-pages.
So thats three levels of hierarchal data presented.
Example:
[image]

Right now its populated using asp:Treeview for easier display of the +(maximise) and -(minimise) images and all.
Is that the best method?
What are the alternatives?

I have some complex calculations and so would like to access all rows, sub-rows and sub-sub-rows easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hierarchical data display can be tricky to do without a hierarchical control, especially if unlimit levels of nesting are needed (potentially, even though most people don't hit the max).  TreeView is a good option, or if with finite levels of nesting, nested data bound controls is an option (but treeview would be better).

TreeView allows you to use the value of the node to find by, so that might be your best option.  Third-party tree controls are even better, if you have the money.

HTH.

Comment: ended up using nested gridviews